# How to properly implement custom regex validator for reactive form in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular6

I am using angular 6. I am trying to validate an email by using regular expression pattern but am not able. Problem is when I am trying these code to validate. Below error message is shwoing:

> ReactiveFormComponent.html:12 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pattern' of null

//ts file

```
   constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
   this.personForm = fb.group({
  'emailAddress': ['', Validators.compose ([Validators.required, 
   Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern)])],
});
}
```

// html file

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
  <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="emailAddress">
  <mat-error *ngIf="personForm.controls['emailAddress'].errors.pattern">
    Invalid Email.
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Can you please share the value of `emailPattern`.

Comment: i have solved my problem. thanks@narm

Answer (score 2):

This question mark fixes your problem:

```
*ngIf="personForm.controls['emailAddress'].errors?.pattern"
```

For valid input content the `errors` property is `null`. And there is no the `pattern` property in `null` indeed. You can see this if add a value changes listener and log the `errors` property value for a different input content:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.personForm.get('emailAddress').valueChanges.subscribe(_ => {
    console.log(this.personForm.get('emailAddress').errors);
  });
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzxeyu) example